# Is there a way to create arrow subSymbol on top of geometry generated symbol using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, symbology

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to set a subsymbol for a PyQGIS generated geometrygeneratorsymbol layer. As can be found in the code I tried multiple things resulting in crashing the kernel or nothing at all. The images represent the manual workflow which works fine. I am interested in transferring this 'Simple line' option to 'Arrow' in an automated way. [image: Geometry generated line] [image: Geometry generated line with arrow as subsymbol]

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsSingleSymbolRenderer,
    QgsLineSymbol,
    QgsFillSymbol,
    QgsProject,
    QgsRectangle,
    QgsArrowSymbolLayer,
    QgsMultiRenderChecker,
    QgsProperty,
    QgsSymbolLayer,
    QgsMapSettings,
    QgsSymbol
)

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer,  QgsProject
layer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query=SELECT from_country, ubc_processing_plant, delivered_tonnes_2019, make_line(Centroids_countries.geometry, UBC_processing_2030.geometry) FROM ubc_flows JOIN Centroids_countries ON ubc_flows.from_country = Centroids_countries.NUTS_NAME JOIN UBC_processing_2030 ON ubc_flows.ubc_processing_plant = UBC_processing_2030.name", "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

def test_3(self):
        sym = self.renderer().symbol()
        
        shape_sym = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({'geometryModifier': 'difference(difference(make_line(start_point($geometry), centroid(offset_curve($geometry, length($geometry)/-10.0)), end_point($geometry)), buffer(start_point($geometry), 10000)), buffer(end_point( $geometry), 10000))', 'outline_color': 'black', 'symbolType': '1'})
        shape_sym.setSymbolType(QgsSymbol.Line)
        
        arrow = QgsArrowSymbolLayer.create(
            {
                "arrow_width": "3",
                "head_length": "3",
                "head_thickness": "3",
                "head_type": "0",
                "arrow_type": "0",
                "is_curved": "1",
                "arrow_start_width": "3"
            }
        )
        fill_sym = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple(
            {"color": "#8bcfff", "outline_color": "#000000", "outline_style": "solid", "outline_width": "0.1"}
        )
        
        #shape_sym.setSubSymbol(arrow)
        #shape_sym.setSubSymbol(sym_layer)
        sym.changeSymbolLayer(0, shape_sym)

test_3(layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to set a subsymbol in PYQGIS qgis 3.x

Replace the sub symbol with the new marker symbol:

```
shape_sym.subSymbol().changeSymbolLayer(0, arrow)
```